# CICS optimization

Tags: db2, cics

I have a CICS program, which will read a DB2 table to obtain the rules based of the field name. Let's say my record type is AA and this type will have at least 20 rules that I need to do loop in DB2 tables. Like wise I have few record types and many more rules tied to each type.

I get data from MQ and for each record type I call separate CICS program. So when I have to process high load, DB2 rules table is getting held by so many program and this causing performance issue.

I want to get away from DB2 and load this rules in CICS Container and maintain periodically. But I'm not sure if this will work. I don't want to use or create VSAM's. I'm looking for some kind of storage I could use and maintain in CICS.

My question is. If I create a pipeline and container will I able to access them by multiple program at a same time and will data stored rules stay in Container after successful get?

Comment: Been a long time since I have used CICS, but 2 options TS Queues & VSAM. For TS Queue you try to read from the TS Queue, if that fails read from DB2 and create the TS Queue. If DB2 table uis updated, just delete the TS Queue which will force a reload of the TS Queue. For VSAM you rebuild the VSAM file from the DB2 table in batch at night

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try to use TS Queue and let know how it works.
Question: If I delete TS Queue and while re-loading, I may have multiple transaction trying use read the TS queue. Is there way I can make the other transaction wait till I completed the re-load?

Comment: Probably there is a way to acquire a lock, but it was a long time ago. Also we used to have 1 record in the TS Queue holding control info & array for the data. Rules tables are probably not changed very often. Also I think you can single stream a Cics Transaction. Talk to a CICS expert most sites have existing standards for this sort of thing

Comment: Thanks. I will give a try and let you all know about the results.

Answer (score 0):

Before reading further, please understand that DB2 solves all the sharing and locking problems very efficiently.  I've never encountered a problem with too many transactions trying to read a DB2 table concurrently.  Updating, yes; a mix of updates and reads, yes; just reading, no.

So, in order to implement your own caching of a DB2 table inside CICS you need a data store.  As @BruceMartin indicates, a TS queue is an option, I would say that given your other constraints it is your only option.

In order to automate this you must create a trigger on your DB2 table that fires after INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.  The trigger must cause the TS queue to be repopulated.  The repopulation mechanism could be EXCI or MQ, as the code performing the repopulation must execute within CICS.

During the repopulation, all transactions reading the TS queue must wait for the repopulation to complete.  This can be done with the CICS ENQ API, with a caveat.  In order to prevent all these transactions from single-threading through their TS queue read due to always ENQing, I suggest using two TS queues, one holds the DB2 data and the other is a "trigger" TS queue.  The contents of the trigger TS queue are not significant, you can store a timestamp, or "Hello, World", or "ABC" it doesn't matter.

A normal transaction attempts a read of the trigger TS queue.  If the read is unsuccessful the transaction simply reads the TS queue with the DB2 data.  But if the read is successful then repopulation is in progress and the transaction ENQs on a resource (call it XYZ).  On return from the ENQ, DEQ and read the TS queue with the DB2 data.

During repopulation, a program executed by the trigger on the DB2 table executes in CICS.  First ENQing on resource XYZ, then creating the trigger TS queue, then deleting the TS queue with the DB2 data, then creating the TS queue and populating it with the new DB2 data, deleting the trigger TS queue, finally DEQing resource XYZ.  I would strongly suggest using a multi-row SELECT to obtain the DB2 data as it is *significantly* more efficient than the traditional OPEN CURSOR, FETCH, CLOSE CURSOR method.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the such brief explanation. I will give a try and will let you know the results.